# Is there any way that I can see what is on a phone that has a cracked screen

Tags: broken-screen

My son was in a wreck and his phone was crushed is there any way I can find out what was on the phone if I connect it to my computer

Comment: The answer lies in the tag you used in your question. Please search it thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the phone has no security lock enabled, you should be able to see the media it contains if connected to a computer. If it has a memory card, you can try and use it on another device.

Assuming the phone is synced to an online account, its contacts, messages, etc. may be accessed by visiting the account online through a computer, preferably.

The only other choice I see is to repair it.